# 401 authorization error after Google cloud endpoints signin

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authorization, google-cloud-endpoints, clientid

I am receiving a 401 authorization error after trying to sign in with Google cloud end points. I am using a client ID that I created in the Google developer console and that is supposed to work locally where I am testing the app (localhost:8080). I am using the following scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

Where do you recommend to start troubleshooting or is there something else obvious that I am missing?

```
google.appengine.bandwidth_bid_ask.signin = function(mode, callback) {
  gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: google.appengine.bandwidth_bid_ask.CLIENT_ID,
      scope: google.appengine.bandwidth_bid_ask.SCOPES, immediate: mode},
      callback);
};
```

I am receiving this error response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Comment: Please add more details on how you're making a call (e.g. python script using Google APIs client lib, etc.).